# Two different youtube embeds, twice the same video

Tags: html, video, youtube, embed, offline

I am writing a video portfolio for future employers in HTML, in my portfolio I embedded YouTube video's via their inbuilt HTML embedder.

In Google Chrome the embedded video's work properly, but in FireFox they don't:

I have three different video's embedded in my portfolio, the first video is displayed properly, the second also, but the third refuses to show. Instead it just shows my second video while I used the embed code of the third.

Here is the website code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Portfolio Adriaan Boer</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#E2FF9C">
<FONT size="4" face="Arial" color="black"
<p>
<center>
Welkom op mijn portfolio, hier volgen enkele items die ik heb gemaakt/ aan heb meegeholpen (een internetverbinding is vereist omdat de filmpjes allemaal hierop te vinden zijn). Daarnaast is er een korte uitleg over mij te vinden op de "Over mij" pagina, hier is ook mijn CV te vinden (onderaan de pagina). 
<br>
</br>
De items staan gesorteerd op volgorde van productieopname, de nieuwste bovenaan.
</p>
</center>
<br>
</br>
<center>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ypiUih_QI5g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p>
Houdbaarheidsdatum: Onbeperkt, mijn oud stagengenoot bij RTi Hilversum Dennis van der Ploeg leidt aan de Ziekte van Duchenne waardoor hij in een rolstoel zit. Om aangemomen te worden bij BNN-VARA moest hij een solcitiatiefilmpje maken van zijn format. Hier heb ik bij geholpen door het te filmen en te monteren/ de post-productie te doen.
</p>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mPbNnFZeXdQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p>
Cyclotron is een korte speelfilm, gemaakt voor de 48hour van Neimegen. Hiervoor heb ik het geboomed en de audio nabewerkt.
</p> 
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1tcX0s5KLyw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p>
RTi Bezoekt is het programma van Lenn Fransche waarin wij op bezoek gaan bij leuke of opvallende plekken in Hilversum. Dit keer zijn wij op bezoek gegaan bij het Fransche kamp, een 'Amsterdams' kampeerterrein vlak bij Bussem. Voor dit programma heb ik het camerawerk verzorgt en de na-montage gedaan.
</p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

My first video is "Onbeperkt pilot", the second is "Cyclotron" and the third is supposed to be "RTi Bezoekt: De Fransche Kamp".

What am I doing wrong?

P.s.:
The web-page is not meant for on-line usage, just for off-line viewing.

Comment: It's work for me on Firefox. http://output.jsbin.com/fugopu

Comment: Same with me. @Adriaan Boer, you're not doing anything wrong...

Comment: Thanks guys, my guess is that the problem came from the YouTube embed service, since it now works properly for me also.

Comment: Update: I have deleted the first YouTube video: 'Houdbaarheidsdatum: Onbeperkt' by request of the producer. Naturally I also deleted the reference in my portfolio. Now, I think YouTube's embed service thinks that the second video is my first video. The 'Cyclotron' video is shown as 'Houdbaarheidsdatum: Onbeperkt', so it now shows a dead link instead of 'Cyclotron'. My guess is that YouTube just needs some time to process different embedded video's on the same page, like mine (or the way I made it).

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this exact same problem and was completely stumped. I had two unique YouTube embeds on my page, but in Firefox only, the second video was appearing as a duplicate of the first (whereas Safari, Chrome, etc. displayed two different videos, as expected).

It appears to be some sort of bizarre caching issue specific to Firefox. But clearing the cache alone didn't help; I had to actually *rename* my page. As soon as I did so, the videos displayed properly. Then I simply changed the name back.

Comment: This is accurate. I did CMD + Shift + R to do a hard refresh and that did it for me.

Comment: I just ran into the same thing myself and hard refreshing also fixed it for me.